# Get error when loading assets in Lotusrb

Tags: ruby, hanami

I am trying out Lotusrb framework and I am having problems with assets. I followed the instructions for using in lotus from [lotus-assets in github](https://github.com/lotus/assets) but I get the error `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ realpath_rec`.

The error happens when I do:

```
Lotus::Assets.configure do
  compile true

  define :stylesheet do
    sources << [
      'app/web/assets/stylesheets' # this is the path to my stylesheets
   ]
  end
end
```

And then in my template:

```
<%= stylesheet 'application' %>
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you generated your app from `lotus new` then I think you have a typo. Lotus generates an `apps` directory. Try this:

```
Lotus::Assets.configure do
  compile true

  define :stylesheet do
    sources << [
      'apps/web/assets/stylesheets' # you had 'app/web/assets/stylesheets'
   ]
  end
end
```